# (IAsyncOperation for non WinRT types) Run coroutine task on Windows thread pool

Tags: c++-winrt, c++-coroutine, cppwinrt

I'm trying to provide co-routine support for non WinRT types that will asynchronously execute on the Windows thread pool.

[cppcoro](https://github.com/lewissbaker/cppcoro) and [libunifex](https://github.com/facebookexperimental/libunifex) both provide the equivalent coroutine task type `task<T>`. I imagine it would be a good idea to run these tasks on the windows thread pool, but maybe I'm just being silly and should just use one of the thread pools provided these libraries.

On the other hand, I was hoping to see how cppwinrt handles this but I cant penetrate definition of `IAsyncOperation`

```cpp
template <typename TResult>
    struct __declspec(empty_bases) IAsyncOperation :
        winrt::Windows::Foundation::IInspectable,
        impl::consume_t<winrt::Windows::Foundation::IAsyncOperation<TResult>>,
        impl::require<winrt::Windows::Foundation::IAsyncOperation<TResult>, winrt::Windows::Foundation::IAsyncInfo>
    {
        static_assert(impl::has_category_v<TResult>, "TResult must be WinRT type.");
        IAsyncOperation(std::nullptr_t = nullptr) noexcept {}
        IAsyncOperation(void* ptr, take_ownership_from_abi_t) noexcept : winrt::Windows::Foundation::IInspectable(ptr, take_ownership_from_abi) {}
    };
```

Kenny Kerr did a talk at cppcon 2016 on this so maybe ill try watching that and then try greping the source code/generated headers.

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding, what the concrete question is. Are you trying to provide co-routine support for your custom types that can asynchronously execute on the thread pool? In that case you'll find the answer in the source code for C++/WinRT, plus lots of reading through [The Old New Thing](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/).

Comment: @IInspectable looking at the cppwinrt generated headers was the first thing I did, but I'll try again. McNellis gave an unusually lucid talk on co-routines  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZTqHjjm86Bw so I'm not stuck, just cant find an easy solution

Comment: The easy solution is not to try to reinvent coroutine promises (which are quite complicated). Wrap your non-WinRT type inside an IInspectable and then return an IAsyncOperation<IInspectable>, and then fish the non-WinRT type back out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most hardest part about learning to implement coroutines is disambiguating the difference between awaitable types and coroutine promise types.

```cpp
concept awaitable:
    await_ready() -> bool
    await_suspend(coroutine_handle<> handle) -> void
    await_resume() -> void
```

```
concept promise_type:
    get_return_object() -> coroutine_return_type<T>
    return_value(T const& v) -> void
    unhandled_exception() -> void
    initial_suspend() -> awaitable
    final_suspend() noexcept -> awaitable
```

For now, I only need to poll if the object returned by my coroutine is ready (rather than `co_await` it), but I need to be able to await on `winrt::resume_on_signal` in the coroutine. cppwinrt does the work implementing the awaitable type in `winrt::resume_on_signal` and I need to do the work implementing the promise type returned by the coroutine I call `winrt::resume_on_signal` in.

The simplest possible type you could return from a coroutine might be `std::shared_ptr<std::optional<T>` and specializing coroutine_traits allows you to do this:

```cpp
namespace std::experimental
{
template <typename T, typename... Args>
struct coroutine_traits<std::shared_ptr<std::optional<T>>, Args...>
{
    struct promise_type
    {
        using result_type = std::shared_ptr<std::optional<T>>;
        result_type result = std::make_shared<std::optional<T>>(std::nullopt);

        result_type get_return_object() {  return result; }
        void return_value(T const& v) {  *result = std::optional<T>(v); }
        void unhandled_exception() { assert(0); }
        std::experimental::suspend_never initial_suspend() { return{}; }
        std::experimental::suspend_never final_suspend() noexcept { return{}; }
    };
};
}
```

which you can use as

```
std::shared_ptr<std::optional<int>> my_coroutine2(HANDLE h)
    {
        co_await winrt::resume_on_signal(h);
        co_return int(1);
    }
...
auto shared_optional = my_coroutine2();
if (*shared_optional)
{
    auto result = **shared_optional;
}
```

However, there are caveats. You will create a race condition if you also make this an awaitable type [oldnewthing](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20210406-00/?p=105057), although I don't beleive you even could make it awaitable because you need to be able call a continuation when the value is set. And it doesn't handle exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**: In hindsight, I could have just used `CreateThreadpoolWait` and never bothered with coroutines.

The performance of `concurrency::task` is very good, so that may have been a better solution to my problem, but I'm familiar with cppwinrt coroutines and they provide a very convenient `winrt::resume_on_signal` which I will use.

If you want to learn how to implement coroutine promise types I recommend watching [James McNellis' talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZTqHjjm86Bw).

For how cppwinrt implements their asynchrony with coroutines watch https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v0SjumbIips (they do it by specializing `coroutine_traits`)

```cpp
template <typename... Args>
    struct coroutine_traits<winrt::Windows::Foundation::IAsyncAction, Args...> {...}
```

But I just followed Raymond Chen's advice and wrote a wrapper around `IInspectable`

```
template<typename T>
struct IInspectableWrapper : winrt::implements<IInspectableWrapper<T>, winrt::Windows::Foundation::IInspectable>
{
    IInspectableWrapper(T state) : state_(state) {}

    static winrt::Windows::Foundation::IInspectable box(T state)
    { 
        return winrt::make<IInspectableWrapper>(state);
    }
    static T unbox(const Windows::Foundation::IInspectable& inspectable)
    {
        return winrt::get_self<IInspectableWrapper>(inspectable)->state_;
    }

private:
    T state_;
};
```

Which can be used

```
winrt::Windows::Foundation::IAsyncOperation<IInspectable> my_coroutine()
    {
        co_return IInspectableWrapper<int>::box(1);
    }

...

auto boxed_result = co_await my_coroutine();
auto result = IInspectableWrapper<int>::unbox(boxed_result);
```

Although the unboxing is unsafe.

Answer (score 0):

Also you could just pass an out parameter to you coroutine and return an `IAsyncAction`

```
winrt::Windows::Foundation::IAsyncAction my_coroutine3(std::weak_ptr<int> weak_i)
{
    if(auto shared_i = weak_i.lock())
        *shared_i = 1;
}
...
auto i = std::make_shared<int>();
auto action = my_coroutine3(i);
auto future = std::tuple{std::move(i), std::move(action)};
```

Comment: This is dangerous if the coroutine is cancelled. The caller may continue before the coroutine body abandons the operation. Safer is to pass the shared_ptr to the coroutine.

Comment: I suppose this is the kind of thing rust-lang would catch. Maybe I should understand rust